# Is there a word for something that gets "acted upon"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, antonyms, agent-nouns

For instance, say I have two individuals and one is active, the other passive. I know I can call the active person the "actor"—he "acts upon" the passive person. But what do I call the "acted upon"? Is there a single word to describe this?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Can you be more specific about under what circumstances the two subjects are engaged?  Is it violent or romantic or a employer/employee situation?  Any additional information would be helpful because there could be a number of possible words, depending on the context of the interaction or relationship.

Answer (score 9):

The term is ***[Patient](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsPatientAsASemanticRole.htm)***, which is formed from the same semi-deponent Latin verb (*patior, patere, passus* 'suffer, endure') as ***[Passive](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsPassiveVoice.htm)***. Most grammatical terminology comes from Latin, so if you want to make up a linguistic term, get a Latin dictionary.

In a prototypical English active transitive sentence,

- the grammatical relation **Subject** has a semantic role **Agent** (< *ago, agere, egi, actus* 'do'),
  while
- the grammatical relation **Direct Object** as the semantic role of **Patient**.

Comment: Because I didn't know this usage, I opened a "Google Incognito" window so the Instant feature would tell me what other people search for without being biased by my previous search history. Once I'd typed in "**agent and**", the fourth alternative auto-complete was *agent and patient* (behind *agent and principal* and separate entries for *agent anderson* with/without *criminal minds*). That's enough to convince me I haven't been paying attention, and it's obviously common knowledge to many, not just an obscure academic usage. But thanks for larning me, all the same!

Comment: The idea is to have separate terminology for the grammatical relations (Subject, Direct Object, etc.) and the semantic relations (Agent, Patient, Experiencer, Receiver, etc.). That way, if you're careful, you have a chance, at least, of avoiding some confusion. There's enough to go around in any case.

Comment: Unless you tell me it's seriously flawed, I think I'll just bookmark [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation) and use those terms if/when I remember. There are certainly enough to go around - it says *there are no clear boundaries between these relations*, implying there are more category terms available than there are unambiguously differentiated categories.

Comment: That sounds right. Not only do languages and dialects vary, but people vary individually as well. Unambigously differentiated categories are possible only with sufficient knowledge of the background context ("boundary conditions", as they call them in PDEs).

Comment: Well, it says there that *in "the hammer broke the window", some linguists treat hammer as an agent, some others as instrument, while some others treat it as a special role different from these*. Are you saying that given sufficient context (plus your intimate knowledge of both the terminology and the possible referents), you'd normally expect to come down heavily in favour of one categorisation or another? I just assumed it meant you might choose your categories according to how you want to analyse the broader context within which they occur.

Comment: Categorization is a tool; there are advantages to having a matched set of power tools. On the other hand, sometimes simple hand tools do the job easier. It's the linguist who uses the term who decides how they use it and what they use it for. That's why (e.g) McCawley gives so many examples -- because the categories are not obvious by name. This uncertainty as to the interpretation of semantic roles and their overlap with grammatical relations is the root of "Case Grammar", "Construction Grammar", "Role and Reference Grammar", "Frame Grammar", and and other cognitive grammatical theories.

Comment: Nice analogy. I suppose metaphorically you'd be the guy who has separate [posidriv and supadriv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives) screwdrivers, where I think I'm doing well because I have some Phillips screwdrdivers (DIY flatpacks often come with "hybrid" screws that can be turned using a standard flat-blade, but a Phillips gives a better grip).

Comment: Sure. All tool users have their own habits of use. Sometimes the important thing is the grip instead of how sharp or big it is. One uses what tools are available, but in giving instructions, one needs to exemplify constantly. Otherwise nobody understands, or rather they understand their way, which may or may not be your way.

Comment: I'm a little sorry they didn't choose 'victim'.

Comment: "Experiencer" generally covers that, though one could add "Adversative" for special cases like the Subject of _He had his tires slashed_.

Answer (score 6):

In Functional Grammar the person or thing acted upon is the *Patient*.

This may seem an odd use of the word, but it is not, in fact, a coinage of modern linguistics.  *Patiens* (the present participle of *pati*, “to undergo, endure, suffer”) and *agens* were literal Latin translations of Aristotle’s terms, and the opposition has been used in English since the 16th century:

> The eye of the man is the arrow, the bewtie of the woman the white, which shooteth not but receiueth, being the patient, not the agent. —Lyly, *Euphues* 1580
>
> Love or hate, applaud or condemn, the agents and the patients of [Shakespeare's] mundane scheme. —Swinburne, *Essays & Studies* 1875

Answer (score 3):

In some circumstances, the term *object* can be used, as in

> She was the *object* of his affections.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/object_3) defines it as

> the particular person or thing to which others direct thoughts, feelings, or actions: *The court has been the object of recent criticism*

Somewhat ironically, the term *subject* may also be used.  Definition 5 in [American Heritage](http://www.onelook.com/?w=subject&ls=a) says

> One that experiences or is subjected to something: *the subject of ridicule.*
>   A person or animal that is the object of medical or scientific study: *The experiment involved 12 subjects.*
>   A corpse intended for anatomical study and dissection.
>   One who is under surveillance: *The subject was observed leaving the scene of the murder.*

Comment: Hmm....but I am looking for something other than "subject/object." Is there an equivalent, like "actor/X"?

Comment: @V - There are a number of specific terms, such as *target, victim, focus, butt, recipient*, but each of them is particular to the type of action.

Answer (score 2):

**Actor** is a term used in functional grammar to describe the person or thing that initiates a material **Process** (but not other kinds of Process), that is, some kind of action that takes place in the real world. If you want to be consistent with the use of **Actor** in functional grammar, then the term to use for the person or thing on the receiving end is the **Goal** (not, *pace* John Lawler and StoneyB, the **Patient**). In a mental Process it is the **Phenomenon**, in a Relational Process, the **Value**, and in a Verbal process, the **Verbiage**.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in various computing process models I've constructed that have an Actor role, the role of that which is acted upon has been either a Subject or a Target.

Comment: In functional grammar, the Target is the person a speech is directed at.